# Qt: Minimize application from child widget

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child

I have an application in Qt and whenever I want to minimize the application I use

```
this->showMinimized();
```

However this line will not work inside a child widget (other than in the child's constructor where 'parent' is available).

Other than setting up a signal and slot, is there a way to minimize the application from a  child widget? I'm trying to avoid signals and slots as I'm starting to have a tons of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the window state to minimized. If the parent widget of your child widget is your application main window you should call in your child widget :

```
this->parentWidget()->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
```

It is also possible to save a pointer to the main window in the constructor of your child widget :

```
QWidget * myParent;

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->myParent = parent;

   ...

}
```

and call whenever you want to minimize the application :

```
this->myParent->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers! Using parentWidget() was the simplest and seemingly less costly method which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one Window you can use this approach:

```
QMainWindow* win = qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(QApplication::activeWindow());
win->showMinimized();
```

But i thing signals/slots is probably a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use signal and slot ( but you could in this case ), you can put the window you want to minimize in your constructor of your child widget.